# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1

Tags: java, android, gradle

My build.gradlew is giving me an error Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

```
#Sun Jun 20 15:24:40 BST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Comment: are you connected with vpn?

Comment: No i am not using a von

Comment: can you post all code in github please?

Comment: ok. The code is here https://github.com/RealYusufIsmail/java-watch-face

Comment: I posted the solution

Comment: Ok i will check if it works

Comment: I still get this Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0.

Comment: https://ibb.co/GRx0Hmw

Comment: Are you running your project with java 11?

Comment: I will check. One sec

Comment: So i tried it now and i still get the same error with AS 4.2 the code is in the same plaxe

Comment: https://gist.github.com/RealYusufIsmail/482b8c95e7cbffcb8bd31cb1ce33e832

Comment: can you try in other machine ?

Comment: I only have one and it is a mac

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the ip and https in Android studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compile your project. I recommend  to change the build gradle with this form

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle-wrapper

```
#Sun Jun 20 11:17:23 COT 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

In the gradle app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

It was ok for me with your project. Also i had changed the android studio version for 4.2

[Android studio 4.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?hl=es-419)

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade your gradle and match it